# PowerBI Slicer to filter column headers

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I'm trying to have a slicer that uses certain column headers as a filter.  The visuals are using a measure that is calculated from the "NPS Response" column, and I haven't been able to get my slicer to work while using a measure for the visual.

[Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E0tu.png)

I would like to filter off the headers "Carrier", "Hub", "Brand".

Below is what I'm trying to achieve.

[EX: "Hub" Selected in slicer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpJcK.png)

[Ex: "Carrier" Selected in slicer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZLXJ.png)

Thank you are any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a field parameter.

[image]

Then insert your columns in the dialog box.